# Sharing a springcontext between tests

Tags: java, spring, gradle, spring-boot

We a are running unit tests in a project with springboot, java and the standard gradle test task.    There's lots of @Autowired stuff in the system.   We have on the order of 1000 tests - and springboot takes between 20 and 40 seconds to load for *every test*, which makes up, as you can imagine, the vast majority of the build time.

Is there any way to share a single spring context between all the tests - and if so, how do I tell gradle to use it?

I've done lots of googling and found various things talking about spring xml configuration - we don't have any xml config files as part of our system - and I'd be loath to add them in - so would prefer a solution that didn't involve xml - but if it's the only way, I'd still like it.  Thanks!

Comment: just to be clear on the question are the tests annotated with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(class=xx.class)?

Comment: no - we have @RunWith(StandardTestRunner.class) on the base class - but haven't seen those - will google them.   Do they have to be on every class, or just the testbase?

Comment: These annotations come by default if you have generated a sample boot app from http://start.spring.io.  And the below comment shows the details

Answer (score 0):

To quote the official documentation:

> Once the TestContext framework loads an ApplicationContext (or WebApplicationContext) for a test, **that context will be cached and reused for all subsequent tests that declare the same unique context configuration within the same test suite.**

For more information, take a look at these links from the official Spring documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testing-ctx-management